# Wso2 BPS: request may be stuck

Tags: wso2, bpel

I have process waiting on pick and listening for ReportProcessStageStateService service. For some reason described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679408/wso2-bps-mex-error-with-pick bps fails to receive soap send to this service.
ReportProcessStageStateService is called one at minute, some of this calls cause bps to failed. But more interesting is massage which I get after "few" failures:

There is/are 500 thread(s) in total that are monitored by this Valve and may be stuck

What this message mean and how it can be avoided?

I'm using bps 2.1.2

```
[2013-04-06 06:15:04,523]  WARN - StuckThreadDetectionValve - Thread ""http-nio-8763"-exec-25" has been active for 601,590 milliseconds (since 4/6/13 6:05 AM) to serve the same request for http://10.10.19.231:8763/services/ReportProcessStageStateService and may be stuck (configured threshold for this StuckThreadDetectionValve is 600 seconds). There is/are 500 thread(s) in total that are monitored by this Valve and may be stuck., tenantDomain=null
java.lang.Throwable
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.MyRoleMessageExchangeImpl$ResponseCallback.waitResponse(MyRoleMessageExchangeImpl.java:301)
    at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.MyRoleMessageExchangeImpl$ResponseFuture.get(MyRoleMessageExchangeImpl.java:247)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.BPELProcessProxy.waitForTheResponse(BPELProcessProxy.java:353)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.BPELProcessProxy.onAxisServiceInvoke(BPELProcessProxy.java:172)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.axis2.receivers.BPELMessageReceiver.handleInOutOperation(BPELMessageReceiver.java:100)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.axis2.receivers.BPELMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(BPELMessageReceiver.java:73)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:199)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bridge.BridgeServlet.service(BridgeServlet.java:164)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:154)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.TomcatServer$1.invoke(TomcatServer.java:254)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:396)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:356)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1534)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
[2013-04-06 06:15:04,523] ERROR - BPELProcessProxy - Timeout or execution error when waiting for response to MEX {MyRoleMex#hqejbhcnphr867xnjguf6v [Client hqejbhcnphr867xnjguf6u] calling {http://test.pl/WebService/Report/Process/Stage/State/Service}ReportProcessStageStateService.reportProcessStageState(...)} java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Message exchange org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.MyRoleMessageExchangeImpl$ResponseFuture@20f8b012 timed out(610000 ms) when waiting for a response!
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Message exchange org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.MyRoleMessageExchangeImpl$ResponseFuture@20f8b012 timed out(610000 ms) when waiting for a response!
    at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.MyRoleMessageExchangeImpl$ResponseFuture.get(MyRoleMessageExchangeImpl.java:250)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.BPELProcessProxy.waitForTheResponse(BPELProcessProxy.java:353)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.BPELProcessProxy.onAxisServiceInvoke(BPELProcessProxy.java:172)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.axis2.receivers.BPELMessageReceiver.handleInOutOperation(BPELMessageReceiver.java:100)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.axis2.receivers.BPELMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(BPELMessageReceiver.java:73)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:199)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bridge.BridgeServlet.service(BridgeServlet.java:164)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:154)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.TomcatServer$1.invoke(TomcatServer.java:254)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:396)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:356)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1534)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
[2013-04-06 06:15:04,570] ERROR - AxisServlet - 
java.lang.ThreadDeath
    at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:758)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.handleStuckThread(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:119)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.backgroundProcess(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1391)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1401)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1380)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
[2013-04-06 06:15:04,585] ERROR - CommonsHTTPTransportSender - 
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault
    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:78)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.sendUsingOutputStream(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:409)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:286)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.sendFault(AxisEngine.java:526)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.handleFault(AxisServlet.java:433)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:216)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:199)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bridge.BridgeServlet.service(BridgeServlet.java:164)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:154)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.TomcatServer$1.invoke(TomcatServer.java:254)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:396)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:356)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1534)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.finishDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:1692)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.close(BaseStreamWriter.java:288)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamWriterWrapper.close(XMLStreamWriterWrapper.java:46)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MTOMXMLStreamWriter.close(MTOMXMLStreamWriter.java:188)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMSerializableImpl.java:197)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:74)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: ClientAbortException:  java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:298)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:103)
    at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.flush(UTF8Writer.java:99)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flush(BufferingXmlWriter.java:214)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.close(BufferingXmlWriter.java:194)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.finishDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:1690)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
    at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:184)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:343)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:116)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:94)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:155)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.writeToSocket(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:186)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:261)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.flush(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:116)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.action(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:763)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:298)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:103)
    at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.flush(UTF8Writer.java:99)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flush(BufferingXmlWriter.java:214)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.flush(BaseStreamWriter.java:311)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamWriterWrapper.flush(XMLStreamWriterWrapper.java:50)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MTOMXMLStreamWriter.flush(MTOMXMLStreamWriter.java:198)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMSerializableImpl.java:195)
    ... 33 more
[2013-04-06 06:15:04,663]  INFO - AxisServlet - org.apache.axis2.AxisFault
[2013-04-06 06:15:04,663] ERROR - [bridgeservlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [bridgeservlet] in context with path [/] threw exception [org.apache.axis2.AxisFault] with root cause
java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
    at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:184)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:343)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:116)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:94)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:155)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.writeToSocket(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:186)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:261)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.flush(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:116)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.action(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:763)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:298)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:103)
    at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.flush(UTF8Writer.java:99)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flush(BufferingXmlWriter.java:214)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.flush(BaseStreamWriter.java:311)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamWriterWrapper.flush(XMLStreamWriterWrapper.java:50)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MTOMXMLStreamWriter.flush(MTOMXMLStreamWriter.java:198)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMSerializableImpl.java:195)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:74)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.sendUsingOutputStream(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:409)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:286)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.sendFault(AxisEngine.java:526)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.handleFault(AxisServlet.java:433)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:216)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:199)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bridge.BridgeServlet.service(BridgeServlet.java:164)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:154)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.TomcatServer$1.invoke(TomcatServer.java:254)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:396)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:356)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1534)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Regards

Tomek

Answer (score 0):

BPS 2.1.2 was missing some important configuration operations such as the ability to configure the tread pool size. Can you try this with BPS 3.2.0 version. Also, have you installed bps on top of another product such as wso2 ESB?

Regards
Nandika

Comment: Yes, BPS 2.1.2 was missing some features. I no longer work with BPS so I can't check if new version is working better. At that time we used BPS 2 and 3 as separate products.